# Visual Studio 2013 x64 calling convention optimization for returning shared_ptr

Tags: visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, calling-convention, disassembly

I'm so confused because my disassembled code is different from my knowledge. As I know, first argument is passed by RCX and return value is stored at RAX. But below code use RCX as return value container and pass first argument by RDX. Why does this happen and what is the name of this way?

This is the cpp code I compile:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Zelon {
public:
  int64_t kkk;
  int64_t lll;
};

typedef shared_ptr<Zelon> ZelonPtr;
std::map<std::string, ZelonPtr> aMap;

shared_ptr<Zelon> Find(const std::string& f) {
  auto it = aMap.find(f);
  return it == aMap.end() ? nullptr : it->second;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  std::string k = "zelon";
  ZelonPtr result = Find(k);
  if (result->kkk == 100) {
    cout << "100" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and this is the disassembled code:

```
ZelonPtr result = Find(k);
00007FF6FAC014DE  lea         rdx,[k]  
00007FF6FAC014E3  lea         rcx,[result]  
00007FF6FAC014E8  call        Find (07FF6FAC012B0h)  
00007FF6FAC014ED  nop  
if (result->kkk == 100) {
00007FF6FAC014EE  mov         rax,qword ptr [result]  
00007FF6FAC014F3  cmp         qword ptr [rax],64h
```

This code is compiled in Visual Studio 2013 x64 Release Full optimization.

Comment: You are returning an object, not a simple value that can fit in the RAX register.  So the compiler passes an extra argument to tell Find() where to store that object.

Answer (score -1):

I got a answer from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(VS.80).aspx

It's a method of 'Return Value Optimization', the use of hidden argument.